# Finding the type and assembly language for binary code

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science

Provide the type and assembly language for the following binary value:

> 0000 00 10 000 1 0001 0100 0 000 00 10 0000two (8 points)

R-type instruction

> Binary Value   000000  10000   10001   01000   00000   100000

```
Assembly Code   Op = 0 (Add)    Rs = 16 ($s0)   
Rt = 17 ($s1)   Rd = 8($t0) Shamt = 0   Funct =  (add)

Add $t0, $s0, $s1
```

This is what I have gotten, but I’m unsure if it is correct. I’m unsure on how to convert binary code into instructions of r-type.

Comment: Is this homework, because you do not mention what architecture you are using

Comment: This is a hw problem, using MIPS language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your understunding looks correct**

To analyze the binary instruction take a look at it as you were the CPU trying to execute it.

First have a look at the instruction set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Instruction_formats

The first 6 bits are always the OPcode. Opcode 0 encodes an R-type instruction, so fields `funct` and `shamt` must also be evaluated.
In this case the `opcode=000000` and the values of `funct=100000` and `shamt=00000`.

On for instance this https://opencores.org/projects/plasma/opcodes list  such combination can be identified as the ADD-instruction on the top row.

You have correctly identified the registers

```
rs=10000 16
rt=10001 17
rd=01000 8
```

So putting it all together

```
// R8=R16+R17

ADD R8,R16,R17
```

because of register names conventions this is also known as

```
ADD $t0,$s0,$s1
```